# Python Password Change program with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having trouble getting these checks to work. it is for a password change program using tkinter. The aim is to make sure the password has both capital and lowercase letters, and is more than 8 characters long. the code always outputs false, even when the password should pass all the checks.

```
def check_password():
    global oldpassword_entry
    oldpasswordcheck= oldpassword_entry.get()
    global newpassword_entry
    newpasswordcheck= newpassword_entry.get()
    global newpasswordconfirmed_entry
    newpasswordconfirmedcheck= newpasswordconfirmed_entry.get()
    if oldpasswordcheck == oldpassword:
        if (any(x.isupper() for x in newpasswordcheck) and any(x.islower() for x in newpasswordcheck) and any(x.isdigit() for x in newpasswordcheck) and len(s) >= 8):    
            if newpasswordcheck == newpasswordconfirmedcheck:
                passwordtrue = 'true'
                print(passwordtrue)
                showoldpasswordchange_label.configure(text=newpasswordconfirmedcheck)
            else:
                passwordtrue = 'false'
                print(passwordtrue)
        else:
            passwordtrue = 'false'
            print(passwordtrue)
    else:
        passwordtrue = 'false'
        print(passwordtrue)
               
                

okaybutton_button = ttk.Button(root, text= "Okay", width= 20, command= check_password)
```

the variables at the start of the function come from the entries here:

```
    showoldpassword_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Current Password: ', font=('calibre',10, 'bold'))
    showoldpasswordchange_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'PasswordExample', font=('calibre',10, 'bold'))
    oldpassword_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Old Password: ', font=('calibre',10, 'bold'))
    oldpassword_entry = tk.Entry(root, font=('calibre',10,'normal'), show = '*')
    newpassword_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'New Password: ', font=('calibre',10, 'bold'))
    newpassword_entry = tk.Entry(root, font=('calibre',10,'normal'), show = '*')
    newpasswordconfirmed_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Confirm Password: ', font=('calibre',10, 'bold'))
    newpasswordconfirmed_entry = tk.Entry(root, font=('calibre',10,'normal'), show = '*')
```

when the code is run it makes this box:

[image: tkinterwindowwithlabelsandstuff]

Comment: There’s a lot of code here; can you whittle it down to a [mre] which specifically demonstrates the issue you’re talking about? See also: [ask]

Comment: I also need to make it show the current password at the top, so have used the label.configure(text='etc') to show the new password at the top, but only if it successfully passes all the checks.

Comment: Your conditions contain references to `s` (in `len(s) >= 8`) and `oldpassword`, but those are not shown being defined anywhere (the old password that's shown by the code is hard-coded in the label). I can't tell if those issues are related to the problem you're having or not, since I can't try to run your program without those values. You might improve your debugging ability by printing out *different* messages in every branch, so you can tell which conditions are failing unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

What is `s` in `if (any(x.isupper() for x in newpasswordcheck) and any(x.islower() for x in newpasswordcheck) and any(x.isdigit() for x in newpasswordcheck) and len(s) >= 8):`

Maybe just swap `s` for `newpasswordcheck`?

The code otherwise looks right to me, i havn't tried it though just read it and im missing `s` and `oldpassword` which i'm guessing is the current password as a string?

Comment: i forgot to change s, thank you for spotting that, and oldpassword is just the current password as a string.